# how to use Window-target in perl(redirect or otherwise)

Tags: perl

I have looked up all over the internet for the answer to this question and have come up with no workable options.. I have tried to redirect a user to a separate frame in the same window (called output) so that when the user clicks the submit button it loads up a page in another frame. I have found 2 different ways to do this. HOWEVER both solutions only redirected the current frame to the desired location(for a test the location was www.yahoo.com). Here are my two solutions:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -Tw

print "Location: http://www.yahoo.com/\n";
print "Window-target: output\n\n";
```

the next is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -Tw

use CGI;
my $q = CGI->new;


$q->redirect(
  -location => 'http://www.yahoo.com/',
  -Window-target => 'output',
);
```

I got the idea of Window-target from these sites:

http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=805235

http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=169691

there are others, but I can only post 2 due to having less than 10 reputation. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Ignore those sites. The `Window-Target` header effectively doesn't exist — it was never standardized, and is not supported by most (if any) of the major web browsers.

[Mozilla *attempted* to implement it around 2000](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=37593), but it looks as though the implementation never worked properly, and [the broken code was removed shortly thereafter](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=97459). Comments in the bugs I linked suggest that no browsers other than Netscape Navigator ever implemented this header, so it's been effectively nonexistent for quite some time.

If you want to have a form submit to a specific frame, use the `target` attribute on the form element, e.g.

```
<form method="POST" action="blah.cgi" target="output">
```